# Sorry we could not fetch the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, social-networking

I am facing one issue "Sorry we could not fetch the image" when I am clicking on pin it button:

below is the parameters I am passing
I am not getting what the this is missing :

1) ?url=
2) &media=
3) &description

This is the link which is creating in dailogbox :

http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https://www.elivatefitness.com/lifestrength-ion-wristbands&media=https://www.elivatefitness.com/medias/LFE102-PureSeriesBlackGray.jpg-Default-WorkingFormat-479Wx479H?context=bWFzdGVyfHJvb3R8MTUxOTV8aW1hZ2UvanBlZ3xoNTUvaDFhLzg3OTk2MTg2NjI0MzAuanBnfDViZmIwMzM4ZTQ0NGQyYjQ1NWY2YmJkZTAxMjdjYjhmNjA3ZDk3ZDUwYTI2M2FmNzA1YjBlMTQyNDAyNzI1MTE&description=Combining%20comfort%20and%20improved%20performance%20the%20LifeStrength%20Ion%20Wellness%20Wristbands%20play%20an%20important%20part%20in%20boosting%20energy%20and%20fighting%20the%20negative%20effects%20of%20the%20environment%20around%20us%20to%20bring%20better%20health,%20relieve%20painful%20joints%20and%20encourage%20a%20deeper%20and%20more%20restful%20sleep.%20LifeStrength%20Ion%20Wellness%20Wristbands%20uses%20a%20proven%20method%20that%20combines%207%20natural%20minerals%20and%20gemstones%20into%20a%20slim%20Far-Infared%20infused%20silicon%20wristband%20you%20can%20wear%2024%20hours%20a%20day,%207%20days%20a%20week.%20Together%20the%20powerful%20mixture%20creates%20a%20unique%20band%20that%20emits%20more%20health-producing%20negative%20ions%20into%20your%20environment%20which%20in%20turn%20increases%20the%20flow%20of%20oxygen%20to%20the%20brain%20resulting%20in%20greater%20energy,%20alertness%20and%20an%20overall%20feeling%20of%20well-being.

Please help me out.

```
function pinIt() 
{
    var mediaURL = location.protocol + "//" + location.host
            + '${imgURL}' + "&description=" + "${description}";
    window.open("//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url="+ document.URL + "&media=" + mediaURL,"",'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
}
```

Comment: can you post any relevant code?

Comment: no... when i click on pinit it gives error.

Comment: if you can't show any code, then its really difficult to help you out. sorry.

Comment: awesome. so when are you calling `pinIt()`?

Comment: <img alt="" src="${themeResourcePath}/images/pi.png" class="st_pinterest" onclick="pinIt();">

Comment: From the url you posted, this is the image url `https://www.xyz.com/medias/DNA842-LuxMinuteMinder.jpg-Default-WorkingFormat-479Wx479H?context=bWFzdGVyfHJ` right? I tried accessing that url. It doesn't seem to work. You should probably check that. I don't see any error with your code. Its definitely related to Pinterest. Pinterest might not be able to access that url

Comment: I have changed the domain.

Comment: so shouldn't you be changing the url as well?

Comment: plz check again I have updated the post. and I am able to see image but can not share.

Comment: are you trying to create a chrome extension?

Comment: no... this is just a simple javascript .

Comment: check your javascript console when you run load the link, you should be getting a [Report Only] Refused to load the image 'https://www.elivatefitness.com/medias/LFE102-PureSeriesBlackGray.jpg-Defaul…TQ0NGQyYjQ1NWY2YmJkZTAxMjdjYjhmNjA3ZDk3ZDUwYTI2M2FmNzA1YjBlMTQyNDAyNzI1MTE' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive. refer to this for more info http://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: you should check this out , http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Refused+to+load+the+image+content+security+policy

Comment: @anurupr ok.but I can see pinit button, description and Image loaded on dialog box if i click on pinit button it gives "Sorry we could not fetch the image" msg.

Comment: exactly. so you need to figure out how exactly the content should be sent to the server

Comment: @anurupr thanks I jsut cleared the cache and it is working.